# Binding to Properties Sum

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have 2 labels bound to two int properties. I also have a 3rd label bound to the sum of the other two labels. Lastly, I also have a converter hooked to the 3rd label to change the Foreground colour if the value isn't 0.

I'm not quite sure but I think I'm binding this incorrectly. My converter doesn't seem to be triggering when I need it to. See below complete code for a simplified version of what I'm currently doing.

C#

```
class IVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _lbl1Int;
    public int lbl1Int
    {
        get { return _lbl1Int; }
        set
        {
            _lbl1Int = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(value);
        }
    }

    private int _lbl2Int;
    public int lbl2Int
    {
        get { return _lbl2Int; }
        set
        {
            _lbl2Int = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(value);
        }
    }

    private int _lblOverallInt;
    public string ErrorsWarningsHeader
    {
        get { return "Errors/Warnings: " + _lblOverallInt; }
        set{}
    }
    public int lblOverallInt
    {
        get { return _lblOverallInt; }
        set
        {
            _lblOverallInt = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ErrorsWarningsHeader));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(int newValue, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        lblOverallInt += newValue;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class IsZeroConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((int)value == 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("IsZeroConverter can only be used OneWay.");
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Name="lbl1" Content="{Binding Path=ErrorsWarningsHeader, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <Label.Resources>
            <local:IsZeroConverter x:Key="isZeroConverter"/>
        </Label.Resources>
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=lblOverallInt}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=lblOverallInt, Converter={StaticResource isZeroConverter}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
    <Label Name="lbl2" Content="{Binding Path=lbl1Int, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Label>
    <Label Name="lbl3" Content="{Binding Path=lbl2Int, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Label>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Go</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Button

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ivm.lbl2Int += 1;
    ivm.lbl1Int += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `lblOverallInt` property for the `Convert` method to get invoked.

Your current implementation doesn't make much sense to me. `lblOverallInt` should be a read-only property that returns the sum of the other two properties. Try this:

```
class IVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _lbl1Int;
    public int lbl1Int
    {
        get { return _lbl1Int; }
        set
        {
            _lbl1Int = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("lblOverallInt");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorsWarningsHeader");
        }
    }

    private int _lbl2Int;
    public int lbl2Int
    {
        get { return _lbl2Int; }
        set
        {
            _lbl2Int = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("lblOverallInt");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorsWarningsHeader");
        }
    }

    public string ErrorsWarningsHeader
    {
        get { return "Errors/Warnings: " + lblOverallInt; }
    }
    public int lblOverallInt
    {
        get { return _lbl1Int + _lbl2Int;  }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong usage

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(value);
```

You should pass name of property that has been changed (like in your `lblOverallInt` setter), e.g.

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(lbl1Int));
```

Comment: But I do that to differentiate between the two NotifyPropertyChanged methods. I don't want to add to my overall value when the overall value is changed so I had to have a different NotifyPropertyChanged method which doesn't `lblOverallInt += newValue;`.